# Rails query using object's attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord

I have a model, `Consultation`, and it has two fields `:date` and `:original_date`.  Is it possible to pull all consultations where `:date` is greater than one year after `:original_date` without looping through all `consultations`?

I tried something like this but it didn't work:

```
Consultation.where("date >= ?", self.original_date + 1.year)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Postgres you can do this

```rb
Consultation.where("date >= (original_date + INTERVAL '1 year')")
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html